# Ресайз imageview picasso

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity, picasso

Есть контейнер в нем есть imageview, скажите, как при помощи picasso изображение растягивалось на всю ширину контейнера, а высота выводилась соответствующее растянутому, (то есть сделать resize картинки так, чтобы занимала всю ширину экрана, а значение высоты не важно)?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {
public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    Drawable d = getDrawable();

    if(d!=null){
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }else{
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}}
```

Comment: да но это не с помощью Picasso, вы сами задали этот вопрос.
Тогда способов есть +100500, чтоб это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso пока не имеет такой функции, но если вам необходимо именно с помощью этой библиотеки сменить размер. Самый очевидный вариант.

1.Вы узнаете размеры вашего контейнера. (Причем практически всегда это будет px, поэтому удобно)

2.Вы используете эти размеры и применяете .resize в Picasso.